# Can a IF Statement be used in a Pivot function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement, pivot

I finally figured out how to obatin this through a pivot via some online articles.  However I still have a two issue, the code posted below works fine and returns my results for the span of a year.  Issue that i'm still encountering however is, theres a parmeter being sent into this sproc call 'DateType' and  it can be 'M' or 'Y'. if it's 'M' I need it to follow the logic below. If its 'Y', need it to follow same logic but populate the 'YTD' field.  I'm not sure how to integrate a 'IF' statement into the use of this Pivot, or if its even possible.  Any help with this would be greatly appreicated.

The 2nd issue thats not represented in the code below, is currently the logic shows the results for a span of a year.  However I also need to add next to the result field the rating field.  Example: 'JAN_Result | Jan_Rating | Feb_Result | Feb_Rating...'  Can two fields be pivoted like this?

*UPDATED* Current Logic:

'code'
    Select  EmployeeID
    ,Employee
    ,EmpGroupID 
    ,PA
    ,EmpLevel 
    ,ObjectiveName as Objective 
    ,Objectiveid AS Objectiveid
    ,Weighting
    ,ReportingYear
    ,[1] as JAN_Result
    ,[2] as FEB_Result
    ,[3] as MAR_Result
    ,[4] as APR_Result
    ,[5] as MAY_Result
    ,[6] as JUN_Result
    ,[7] as JUL_Result
    ,[8] as AUG_Result
    ,[9] as SEP_Result
    ,[10] as OCT_Result
    ,[11] as NOV_Result
    ,[12] as DEC_Result
    ,[13] as YTD

```
From

(

Select 
 EmployeeID
,Employee
,EmpGroupID
,PA
,EmpLevel
,ObjectiveName
,Objectiveid
,Weighting
,ReportingYear
,Result
,Rating

,Max(CASE WHEN r.datetype = 'M' THEN Month(startdate) WHEN r.datetype = 'Y' THEN     13        END) as StartMonth

 From #tblResults R

INNER JOIN @Emphist h 
        ON r.Empgroupid = h.Groupid

LEFT OUTER JOIN Config.tblRatingDescription rt
             ON r.Rating = rt.RatingID

LEFT OUTER JOIN Config.tblRatingDescription rtovr
             ON r.RatingOverride = rtovr.RatingID

WHERE r.datetype IN ('M','Y')
and r.startdate BETWEEN  '2012-01-01' AND '2012-04-01'

Group By
EmployeeID, 
Employee, 
EmpGroupID, 
PA, 
EmpLevel, 
ObjectiveName, 
Objectiveid,
ReportingYear,
Weighting,
h.sortorder,
Result,
Rating

)ps


PIVOT
(
max(result)
FOR StartMonth IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13])
) as pvt
```

'code'

Example Data:

```
EmployeeID  Employee  EmpGroupID  PA  EmpLevel  Objective  Jan_Result  Feb_Result 
1010101     TestUser  111         NE CustService  Equip_Res  94.44      9.92
```

Comment: Yes, You can use cross apply/unpivot to achieve the Jan_Result and Jan_Rating for the second issue. For the First issue, are you saying if you pass "Y" to the DataType then you want to show only YTD, not all the fields?

Comment: @Viji Thanks for relpying. As for the Datatype, this will be ran on one employee at a time, how ever that employee may have 5 records. But 4 maybe 'M' and one maybe 'Y'.

Comment: @CadeRoux saw your pivot post on another post and thought you would have some input on this one for me me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is very big. I will not repeat it. Basically, all you need to do is to replace this line:

```
,Month(startdate)     as StartMonth
```

with a:

```
,CASE WHEN r.datetype = 'M' THEN Month(startdate) ELSE 13 END as StartMonth
```

If other values come on board, you can just continue the statement:

```
,CASE WHEN r.datetype = 'M' THEN Month(startdate) WHEN r.datetype = 'Q' THEN 14 ELSE 13 END as StartMonth
```

Comment: Thanks @cha that worked for me. But its creating a row for each month for each 'objectiveid'.  I assume it's doing that because of the Result and rating field being differentfr each month, but I thought that was the whole point of using a pivot was to put all on one row?  DO you have any suggestion on how I can fix this? heres a screen shot of the data data currently[link] http://sdrv.ms/15aXYml [/link]

Comment: I updated the logic above showing how I used you suggestion @cha